# python math wrong answer (not decimals)

Tags: python, math

Why in gods name is it 57.5

[compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yIrW.png)

Comment: Please, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about the format of the questions. I'd suggest 1) changing the title to something more related (Error when performing math operations with input variables, for example) and 2) adding the actual code instead of a screenshot in the question body itself.

Answer (score 3):

`input` return strings, thus `2` + `3` is `23` (the default behaviour for `+` with strings is to concatenate them), then the casting to int turns this into an actual `23`, so finally you get `5 * 23 / 2 == 115 / 2 == 57.5`.

To solve this, cast each parameter to int before doing the math operations:

```
int(h) * (int(a)+int(b)) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You concatenate two string, then turn the result into an int. If you do `int(a) + int(b)` it will work properly.